# Unable to show Share UI in desktop bridge app

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

In native UWP apps, we can show share UI by calling [DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager) method.

```
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

Calling this method in a desktop bridge app raises an exception:

> Element not found.
>
> This method cannot be called while the app is in the background

That's kind of expected as the bridge app does not use the UI elements of UWP. So I tried to use way it should be done in native Win32 apps.

In native Win32 apps, we can show share UI by calling [DataTransferManagerHelper.ShowShareUIForWindow](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/ShareSource/wpf/DataTransferManagerHelper.cs) method. However, this call in a desktop bridge app (that runs in an app context) does nothing but crashing `explorer.exe`. The exact same code works if the app does not run as a bridge app but as a native Win32 app.

```
IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle; 
DataTransferManagerHelper.ShowShareUIForWindow(hwnd);
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

This issue has been fixed on build 17024. I successfully ran the code to open share UI on the latest insider build (17101).

Comment: Thanks for reporting this Mehrzad - this doesn't sound like the expected behavior. We are investigating.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Thanks for the response Stefan, Hope to get an update on this in future.

Comment: The fix has been available in public Windows Insider builds for a couple of weeks now. If you have a chance to try that, please let me know if you still see any issues. Thanks again for reporting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed that this is a bug. ShowShareUIForWindow() would be the right API to call for your scenario, once the bug is fixed.

I have assigned the bug to the right team now.

Thank you for reporting the issue!

**Update**

Fix is available in build 17024 and above

Comment: The fix has been available in public Windows Insider builds for a couple of weeks now. If you have a chance to try that, please let me know if you still see any issues. Thanks again for reporting!

Comment: Thank you for your update and fixing the bug Stefan! I guess I will wait until the next official update or sooner if I get some free time to install an insider build. I will let you know when I try it.

Comment: I tested the code on build 17101 and it works now! Thanks.