# Displaying Share UI over a small Window

Tags: desktop-bridge

I'm using the [IDataTransferManagerInterop.ShowShareUIForWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idatatransfermanagerinterop-showshareuiforwindow) class to display share ui in a desktop bridge app.

The problem is, the application window has a small height and the share UI appears with the same height as the application window. With such small height, the share UI is unusable.

[image: Share UI]

Maybe the [ShowShareUI(Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.showshareui#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataTransferManager_ShowShareUI_Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_ShareUIOptions_) overload method of the DataTransferManager class could help adjusting the size by [SelectionRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.shareuioptions.selectionrect#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_ShareUIOptions_SelectionRect) property, but this overload is not available in the IDataTransferManagerInterop interface.

Comment: Why not use [DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.showshareui) directly in your desktop bridge app?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT It doesn't work (an exception raises) since desktop bridge apps do not have the same UI context as UWP apps. That's why IDataTransferManagerInterop exists.

Comment: `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager` APIs supported in packaged app. I saw that you post this question in your previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327238/unable-to-show-share-ui-in-desktop-bridge-app). Stefan said 'Fix is available in build 17024 and above'. Have you tried it?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT The fix is for IDataTransferManagerInterop to work not for Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI. Yes I tried it again and it throws exception as I posted on that thread, so we have to use IDataTransferManagerInterop and cannot call the method directly.